# how copy from one stringstream object to another in C++?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have `std::stringstream` object `ss1`. Now, I would like to create another copy from this one.

I try this:

```
std::stringstream ss2 = ss1;
```

or:

```
std::stringstream ss2(ss1)
```

neither works

The error message is like this:

> std::ios::basic_ios(const std::ios &) is not accessible from
>   bsl::basic_stringstream,
>   bsl::allocator>::basic_stringstream(const
>   bsl::basic_stringstream,
>   bsl::allocator>&).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Indeed, streams are non-copyable (though they are movable).

Depending on your usage, the following works quite well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss1;
    ss1 << "some " << 123 << " stuff" << std::flush;

    std::stringstream ss2;
    ss2 << ss1.rdbuf(); // copy everything inside ss1's buffer to ss2's buffer

    std::cout << ss1.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss2.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> some 123 stuff
>   some 123 stuff

Comment: Is this more efficient than Pedro d'Aquino's answer, since it seems to be more straight forward.

Comment: @alfC: You have to profile to see, but just guessing this is likely more efficient because it copies from one buffer directly into another, and does not dynamically allocate a string in-between.

Comment: (Now I scrolled down to see the comment in the other answer. Sorry for the repeated question)

Comment: Notice: this will not work with ostringstream / wostringstream because rdbuf() is a reading operation. For `o` streams you still need str() anyway.

Comment: Actually this is only a partial copy. All formattings are lost. They have to be copied manually.

Comment: @GManNickG Isn't this not only a copy - but rather, depending on the implementation (of rdbuf), a move? Means that ss2 now has the data but ss1 does not?

Answer (score 12):

As `std::stringstream` [does not provide](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/stringstream/) a copy constructor, you have to build it from the `std::string` `ss1`outputs:

```
std::stringstream ss2(ss1.str());
```

Comment: The only problem I can see with this is it forces `ss1` to cough up a string, which will then be re-inserted into `ss2`. `rdbuf` just does it directly.

Comment: Agreed. I think this solution is less efficient than the one above, because it requires allocation of a string and two copies.

Comment: Disagree. This post is the right answer, `since ss2 << ss1.rdbuf(); // copy everything inside ss1's buffer to ss2's buffer` actually *moves*  everything inside ss1's buffer. Of course, all these string allocations are less efficient, but they do keep the original buffer intact.