# Problem with ostringstream and copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, ostringstream

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why copying stringstream is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed)
>   [how copy from one stringstream object to another in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442520/how-copy-from-one-stringstream-object-to-another-in-c)

Compiling class T fails with Visual C++ and GCC producing iostreams template errors. Here is the code:

```
#include <sstream>

class T
{
  static T copy;

  std::ostringstream log;

  T()            {}
  T(const T& t)  {log  = t.log;}
  ~T()           {copy = *this;}
};

T T::copy;
```

Changing *log* data member type to string makes it compile and run OK. Is this a legitimate behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy constructor and copy-assignment of any stream class in C++ has been made `private`. That means, you cannot make copy of `std::ostringstream` object:

```
std::ostringstream ss;

std::ostringstream ss1(ss); //not allowed - copy-constructor is private
ss1=ss; //not allowed - copy-assignment is private
```

Comment: OK, that's true, but I'm getting the same error even with empty copy-constructor: `T(const T& t)  {}`

Comment: @Paul: Post the actual code, and the error.

Comment: @Nawasz: Code is as in my question above with copy-constructor replaced with: `T(const T& t) {}` or `T(const T& t) {log << t.log.str();}` or `T(const T& t) {log << t.log.rdbuf();}`. I'm always getting: _'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'_

Comment: @Paul: Alright. That is because of this line `copy = *this;` which invokes `operator=() generated by the compiler; the generated code has this line `copy.log= (*this).log` which is causing problem. That means, if you comment the line `copy=*this;` then it will compile fine. Atleast that error will not show up.

Comment: Thank you. I fell into copy constructor vs. assignment operator trap.

Comment: @Paul: Its not `copy constructor vs. assignment operator trap`. Its *copy constructor **and** assignment operator trap* which I said in the very beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`std::ostringstream` is not copyable that's why you are getting error. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442520/how-copy-from-one-stringstream-object-to-another-in-c) for more details to know how you can overcome this problem.

```
T(const T& t)  {log << t.log.rdbuf(); }
```

Comment: It still produces the same error: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Answer (score 1):

I think **ostringstream** has no overloaded assignment(=) operator.