# Simplest way to create class that behaves like stringstream

Tags: c++, inheritance, stringstream

I'm making a simple `Error` class that should be thrown using `throw` statement, logged or written in console. The basic idea of the usage is:

```
//const char* filename is function argument
if(!file_exists(filename))
  throw Error(line, file, severity)<<"Invalid argument: the file does not exist: "<<filename;
```

I originally wanted to extend `stringstream`, but my searches indicate that [it's impossible to extend on streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11865534/607407).

I'd really like to make the error class as convenient as you can see above, which means able to "*eat*" various types and append them to internal error message.

Comment: An adapter to std::cerr?

Comment: `std::cerr` is just an **instance of** `std::ostream`, such as `std::cout`. It's an instance, not a **class** / **type**. Anyway, I want to store the input, not print it!

Comment: Sorry for so much of bold font, but today I'm gettin' real tired of people who don't read questions/answers thoroughly.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from overloading an operator<<(Error&, const std::string&)? I'd say that this should just work.

Comment: @bialpio Nothing. But then I'd have to overload it for every type supported by `stringstream`.

Comment: Then make the second parameter templated?

Comment: @wakjah And what if the `stringstream` doesn't support value in template? It will then throw confusing errors.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to extend streams. You are misunderstanding the Q&A you've linked to. Please read it again or refer to the documentation before you make such misinformed assumptions.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I don't think it's essentially wrong to do incorrect assuptions about something *when asking question*. In fact, I'm asking here because I was *doing something wrong*, right? Blaming question authors for being misinformed is dumbest thing of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually it's not so hard. You can't inherit from `stringstream` directly - or I just didn't find out how. You'll soon drown in `std` template system...

```
template<class _Elem,
class _Traits,
class _Alloc>
// ... mom help me!
```

But, you can make a template:

```
template <class T>
Error& Error::operator<<(T const& value) {
    //private std::stringstream message
    message<<value;
    //You can also trigger code for every call - neat, ain't it? 
}
```

You'll be adding all values from this method to private variable within the class:

```
class Error
{
public:
    Error(int, const char*, int);
    ~Error(void);
    std::string file;
    unsigned int line;
    //Returns message.str()
    std::string what();
    //Calls message.operator<<()
    template <class T>
    Error& operator<< (T const& rhs);

private: 
    std::stringstream message;

};
```

There's still something I'm missing - how to distinguish between types supported by `stringstream` and others and throw error on the line of call, rather than in `Error` class. Also I'd like to write own handlers for unsupported types.

Comment: What do you mean? This won't compile if `T` doesn't support `operator<<` for `ostream`s, and all you need to do to support unsupported types is just that: provide an overload of the appropriate operator for your type and `ostream`.

Comment: @wakjah It's just that it won't compile and will act like the error was in `Error.cpp` - not in the caller code. As of other overloads, I'll need to look up how templates work...

Comment: Yes, template errors take a bit of getting used to. But you should just let the compiler do its job and emit the error. The alternative would be to implement a SFINAE check and use `static_assert` (e.g., see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768511/using-sfinae-to-check-for-global-operator)), but it's very difficult to get a solution that covers all cases, so if I were you I'd just let the compiler do its job, which will cover all cases. Or wait for concepts to be implemented in your favourite environment :)

Comment: `You can't inherit from stringstream directly` Sure you can, the issue is that streams can't be copied so you can't throw one.