# C++ Stringstream - copying with rd_buf changes const object

Tags: c++, stream, constants, stringstream

Given one stringstream object, I would like to copy it to another. According to :

[how copy from one stringstream object to another in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442520/how-copy-from-one-stringstream-object-to-another-in-c)

(among others), the proper way to do this is to use the `rdbuf()` member. However, this seems to cause issues, particularly if the stringstream is const.

For example:

```
void DoSomething(stringstream & ss)
{
    stringstream sstmp;

    cout << "pos 1: " << ss.tellg() << "\n";
    sstmp << ss.rdbuf();
    cout << "pos 2: " << ss.tellg() << "\n";
//        sstmp.rdbuf()->pubseekpos(0, ios_base::in | ios_base::out);

    cout << "String: " << sstmp.str() << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hello";

    DoSomething(ss);
    DoSomething(ss);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
pos 1: 0
pos 2: 5
String: Hello
pos 1: 5
pos 2: 5
String:
```

The first call to `DoSomething()` changed the internal pointer, and seems to do so even if the `stringstream` is const (left out here as even `tellg()` is not const). The way to remedy this is with `seekg()`, but that can't be called on const streams. I attempted another way (commented out in the code) but without success.

So what can be done to either:

1. Copy a (const) `stringstream` without really changing it, or
2. reset the position on a const object?

Note: Compiled using gcc 4.8.1 on Arch Linux

Comment: Losing the `tellg()` calls and adding a call to `ss.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::beg, std::ios_base::in);` will likely get what you want, but I'm not sure it will drive home what is the real question for me; why. Someone with deeper understanding of the stream lib will have to step in. Great question, and +1 for doing the initial homework on prospective answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way is to just make the string and copy that way: `sstmp.str(ss.str());`

The less obvious approach is to fully utilize the fact that you can gain non-const access to the `rdbuf` from a const stringstream.

I made several changes so your code compiles, and updated the code to directly set the `rdbuf`'s position, but it should do what you want, now outputting:

```
String: Hello
String: Hello
```

-

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void DoSomething(const std::stringstream& ss)
{
    std::stringstream sstmp;

    sstmp << ss.rdbuf();
    ss.rdbuf()->pubseekpos(0, std::ios_base::in);

    std::cout << "String: " << sstmp.str() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hello";

    DoSomething(ss);
    DoSomething(ss);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I see my typo now. I was so close :) Thanks for confirming