# Why can't an object containing a ostringstream member be constructed?

Tags: c++, c++11, ostringstream, deleted-functions

I have the following class example, simplified from a larger project. It's based on a logging framework that uses the logger's scope to terminate a log entry in the destructor.

The code below will not compile because the constructor is an implicitly deleted function (*edit: not true*), which seems to have something to do with the `std::ostringstream` object. I'm confused about that because I think I should be able to directly construct a `std::ostringstream`, which would mean I should be able to directly construct a `Container` object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Container {
  public:
    std::ostringstream  bufferStream;

  public:
    Container();    // constructor
    ~Container();
};

Container::Container() {
    bufferStream << "Hello ";
}

Container::~Container() {
    std::cout << bufferStream.str() << " [end]" << std::endl;
}

// === Main method ===

int main() {

    Container().bufferStream << "world";   // works fine

    {                                      // causes tons of compiler errors
        Container cont = Container();
        cont.bufferStream << "world!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the line labeled "works fine" does just that. It seems to instantiate an anonymous `Container` object, which contains a new `std::ostringstream`, which can be directly accessed to output "world". The `Container` itself creates the "Hello" part of the message and its destructor flushes the buffer.

Why doesn't the second part, in which the `Container` object is named and saved, run correctly? Here is a sample of the errors I get:

```
error.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
error.cpp:28:36: error: use of deleted function ‘Container::Container(const Container&)’
         Container cont = Container();
                                    ^
error.cpp:4:7: note: ‘Container::Container(const Container&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Container {
       ^
error.cpp:4:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ostringstream<char>::basic_ostringstream(const std::basic_ostringstream<char>&)’
In file included from error.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/sstream:387:11: note: ‘std::basic_ostringstream<char>::basic_ostringstream(const std::basic_ostringstream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_ostringstream : public basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>
```

... and so on.

Comment: Uh, this is not a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3442520/2069064).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would work fine:

```
Container cont;
cont.bufferStream << "world!";
```

But this:

```
Container cont = Container();
```

involves the copy constructor. `std::ostringstream` is not copy-constructible which makes `Container` not copy-constructible, hence the error message talking about how `Container::Container(const Container&)` is implicitly deleted due to `std::basic_ostringstream<char>::basic_ostringstream(const std::basic_ostringstream<char>&)` being implicitly deleted.

Note that even though this copy would be elided, a requirement of copy/move elision is that the copy/move must be possible to begin with.

Comment: Perfect. So the correct statement, `Container cont;`, constructs the container but doesn't copy it. My Java background is showing!

Comment: ... and it invokes the copy constructor because the user-provided destructor suppresses the implicit move constructor.

Answer (score 4):

As Barry explained, the [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/ostringstream/) isn't copy constructible.  As the default copy constructor copy-constructs member by member, it can't be generated here.

However, if you'd follow the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) you'd create a copy constructor (and also a copy assignment operator), [doing what is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442520/how-copy-from-one-stringstream-object-to-another-in-c?lq=1) for the stringstream.  Then it would work:

```
class Container {
    ...
    Container(const Container&); //Copy constructor
};  

Container::Container(const Container &c) {
    bufferStream << c.bufferStream.rdbuf(); 
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/6yERom)