# Access element of vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class Student:

```
class Student {
private:
    unsigned int id;
    string name;
    vector<int> grades;
public:
    Student(unsigned int id, string name, vector<int> grades);;
    virtual ~Student() {}

    unsigned int getId() { return this->id; }
    string getName() { return this->name; }
    int getGradesAmount() { return this->grades.size(); }
    vector<int> getGrades() { return this->grades; }
    int getGrade(int i) { return this->grades[i]; }

    unsigned int getCoef()
    {
        unsigned int coef = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < this->grades.size(); i++) { coef *= this->grades[i]; }
        return coef;
    }

    int getNameCoef() { return this->getName().size() % 2; }

    ostringstream getInfo()
    {
        ostringstream info;
        info << "ID: " << getId() << ".\n";
        info << "Name: " << getName() << ".\n";
        info << "Amount of grades: " << getGradesAmount() << ".\n";
        info << "Grades:";
        for (int i = 0; i < getGradesAmount(); i++)
            info << " " << getGrade(i);
        info << "\nProduct of grades: " << getCoef() << ".\n";
        info << "Is surname has odd number of symbols (0 = no / 1 = yes): " << getNameCoef() << ".\n";
        return info;
    }
};

Student::Student(unsigned int id, string name, vector<int> grades)
{
    this->id = id; this->name = name; this->grades = grades;
}
```

And a class Group:

```
class Group : public Student {
protected:
    int size = 0;
    vector<Student> group;
public:
    Group() : Student(getId(), getName(), getGrades()) {}

    void addStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (student.getNameCoef() == 1)
        {
            if (this->group.size() > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this->group.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (student.getCoef() > group[i].getCoef())
                    {
                        this->group.insert(this->group.begin() + i, student);
                        this->size = this->size + 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            cout << "\nAdded to start";
            this->group.push_back(student);
            this->size = this->size + 1;
        }
    }
};
```

In Group I'm trying to overload << to make a cout << group.
So, I have added this into a Group:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Group& group) { // overloaded operator of output
        out << "\nThere are " << group.size << " students in the group.\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < group.size; i++)
        {
            out << "Student # " << i + 1 << ":\n";
            out << group[i].getInfo();
        }

        return out;
    }
```

But I have this error:

```
error C2676: binary '[': 'const Group' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

So, I googled for any [] overloaded operators for vector but didn't find anything that work for me. I also tried copying constructor, but it didn't helped me.
How to use group[i].getInfo() ? Or maybe there are some oter ways to access this. So, group[i] must be Student object.

Comment: The `group` in your `operator<<` is not a `std::vector<Student>`. It's a `Group` object. Your `Group` class does not have an `operator[]` defined. Therefore, you can't use it on `group`. Since this function is a friend function, you can access private elements directly. Your vector is `group.group`. To access an element of the vector, you'd do `group.group[i]`

Comment: You're misusing inheritance here. `class Group : public Student` means that a `Group` is a type of `Student`, which obviously makes no sense. I suggest you review what inheritance is. Also, the `group` in your `operator<<` overload is not a vector.

Comment: It's also unusual that your `Group` inherits from `Student`. That means a `Group` *is* a `Student`. That doesn't make sense. It looks like `Group` could just get away with being a `std::vector<Student>` named `group` or `students` or something. You also don't need to track the `size` in `Group` since the `std::vector<Student> group` tracks its own size via `group.size();`

Comment: And, to add to the pile of problems, here, `getInfo()` is not a `const` class member. So, after squaring away all of the above issues, if you end up with a `const` object, you can't call its `getInfo()` method, anyway. And if `getInfo()` is changed to a `const` method, any method is calls itself also must be `const`. When you start learning about overloading operators, you'll need to quickly learn, and understand, what `const`-correctness means.

Comment: Copying `std::ostringstream` is not allowed, just like a `std::ostream`. That means you can't return it by value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3442520/10957435

Comment: Group inherits from Student because I can't create vector of objects Student otherwise.

Comment: "Group inherits from Student because I can't create vector of objects Student otherwise." then you're doing something wrong. You don't need to inherit from `std::vector` in order to have a member `std::vector`, so you don't need to inherit from `Student` to use `Student`. What error do you get when you remove the inheritance of `Student` from `Group`?

Comment: @JohnFilleau yes, you are right. I don't need inheritance here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are confusing the `group` which is of type `Group` with its member, which is confusingly also called `group`.

Either you provide an `Group::operator[]` or you change your `operator<<` to

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Group& group) { // overloaded operator of output
        auto& vect = group.group;
        out << "\nThere are " << vect.size() << " students in the group.\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
        {
            out << "Student # " << i + 1 << ":\n";
            out << vect[i].getInfo();
        }

        return out;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code (see comments), but the one you're asking about is because of this line:

```
out << group[i].getInfo();
```

As JohnFileau mentioned, `group` is a `Group` object, not a `std::vector`. If you want to access the `std::vector` `group` in the `Group` class, you will need `group.group`:

```
out << group.group[i].getInfo();
```

This will fix *this* issue, but it's only fair to warn you you will soon hit others. I recommend reading the comments on your question and figuring out how to fix them.

---

Something worth noting here is that part of the reason you're seeing this is you may not realize that `operator<<()` is not a member function of `Group`. That is, even if you define it inline like this:

```
class Group : public Student {
    //...
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Group& group) { // overloaded operator of output
            out << "\nThere are " << group.size << " students in the group.\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < group.size; i++)
            {
                out << "Student # " << i + 1 << ":\n";
                out << group[i].getInfo();
            }

            return out;
        }
};
```

It might look like it's a member of `Group`, but it's actually not. It is an external `friend` function. It is not actually a part of `Group`. That means you can't access the data members directly. For instance,

```
this->size
```

will fail because, again, it's not actually a member function.

If you want to access data members of `Group`, you need to access them via the instance you were passed (i.e., `group`:

```
group.size
```

Note that that means when you do something like `group.size`, you're actually getting data member `Group::size`, not the [`size()` from `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).